# What format do you use to store your stakeholder register?

Tags: stakeholders

I'm trying to update our project management templates and tools for 2012 and looking at all the available online resources and tools. Most are obvious matches (project charters use a word processor, budgets need a spreadsheet, etc.) but I can't decide what is the best way solution for the stakeholder register.

What do you find the most easy to use and easy to maintain? Word? Excel? Custom web-form?

Answer (score 3):

I think most "register" artifacts lend themselves to spreadsheets. Simple. Organized. Sortable.